# PdfBox and iTextSharp strange behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I am working on a Windows Forms Application with C# and my application converts PDF file to text. For example, I have the following citation:

> NEVILLE, C. (2010) The Complete Guide to Referencing and Avoiding Plagiarism. 2nd edition. Maidenhead: Open University Press.

It is a multi line text. The conversion works fine but with one problem - the citation is returned as two different rows - the first one ends with the full stop after edition and the other one starts from Maidenhead. And this makes my further work impossible. It doesn't preserve the real format.
Could you suggest a solution to that problem?

Comment: *It doesn't preserve the real format.* - what you call *real format* is not explicitly present in the pdf. All there (generally) is,  are text fragments positioned somewhere on the page. Thus, text extraction basically can return lines of text at best.  You as a human recognize paragraphs etc in the pdf visually. One can try and code text structure recognition routines. Such routine recognize a certain degree of false structures,  though.

Comment: What mkl says is correct. Ordinary PDFs don't have any semantic structure *unless they are tagged.* So before the question can be answered, we need the answer to a counter-question: is your PDF tagged? If not, you're out of luck.